# Segmentation Fault during high load concurrency test with WebWorker Threads

Tags: javascript, multithreading, node.js

So, I'm trying to conduct a test to see how much WebWorker Threads (https://github.com/audreyt/node-webworker-threads) can improve CPU intensive tasks with NodeJS in a multi core system.

I actually got this working on a VM with a single core assigned at work, but when I tried it on my home VM with 4 cores, I'm getting a Segmentation Fault after 15-20 requests.

I've got my project up at https://github.com/WakeskaterX/NodeThreading.git

I have tried eliminating pieces to see why I'm getting the SegFault, but even just returning static numbers throws the SegFault after 15-20 requests.

For the loadtest command I'm running:

```shell
 loadtest -c 4 -t 20 http://localhost:3030/fib?num=30
```

It runs just fine when it's synchronously calculating the Fibonacci sequence, but as soon as it hits a web worker it Segmentation Fault Core Dumps.  Perhaps this is related to the WebWorker-Threads code on the back end, but I'm mainly wondering why it's happening and how I can debug it further or fix it so I can test background threading in nodejs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is a variable lifetime issue — In general, a long-running worker needs to be assigned into an object, instead of a lexical variable; the latter is garbage-collected away when the scope exits.

See https://github.com/WakeskaterX/NodeThreading/pull/1 for the pull request that fixes the issue.

Comment: This did solve the Seg Fault issue.  I definitely just need to use pools though, this burned through all the memory on my VM so I'll need to delegate that to a limited amount of threads.  Thanks again for looking into this!